# How can I get a string between some tags, but BEFORE "</table>", with a regex?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

```
/<table[\s]+cellspacing="0"[\s]+class="cj(?:.*?)"[\s]+id="(?:.*?)">(?:.*?)value="(.*?)"(?:.*?)<td[\s]+class="dep">(.*?)<\/td>(?:.*)(?:<td[\s]+class="arr">(.*?)<\/td>)+(?:.*?)<\/table>/
```

This is my current regex string, used in PHP with `preg_match_all()`. I replaced `(?:.*?)` with `(?:.*)` so that instead of getting the first `<td>` with `class="dep"`, it gets the last one. Now, this works perfectly, unless there is more than one table, in which case it gets the last `<td>` with `class="dep"` from the entire parsed string. Can anyone help me understand what I did wrong?

Also, I know I should have used XML parsing, but it seemed way too complicated for me :P

Edit: Also, what I actually want is the `<td>` that is before the first `</table>` tag.

Comment: You really should use xml parsing for that. String operations with regex should be the last solution you think about. And xml parsing with php is not that complicated.

Comment: I know, but I spent like a week trying to get it to work with XML, while this regex took me only 2 days (no previous experience).

Comment: Can you please provide some example xml?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ended up fixing it by getting the table with one regex, then parsing its contents with another.

Answer (score 0):

This simple pattern

```
$pattern = "#<table\s.*?>.*?<td\s.*?class=[\"']dep[\"'].*?>(.*?)</td>.*?</table>#i";
```

returns data from first matched pair **`<td...class="dep"...>`** and **`</td>`** tags from inside **EVERY** table in subject string (doesn't matter how many tables you have).

This is case insensitive search and also it would match both, single and double quotes around class name (**`class="dep"`** or **`class='dep'`**).

Note: if you have more `<TD>` tags with `class="dep"` inside single table, this pattern returns data from first appearance of TD pair with that class.

sample code would be like this

```
$pattern = "#<table\s.*?>.*?<td\s.*?class=[\"']dep[\"'].*?>(.*?)</td>.*?</table>#i";
$document = ''; // put here your subject string
preg_match_all($pattern, $document, $results);
print_r($results[1]);
```

Cheers!